# generator of ring class field extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

everyone! I have another questions. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ be an imaginary quadratic field and let $p\equiv 8\mod 9$ be a prime. Denote $H_{3p}$ and $H_{p}$ for the ring class field of $K$ with conductor $3p$ and $p$. $H_{3p}/H_{p}$ is a degree $3$ field extension. Does anyone know what is the generator of the extension or how to find it?